# Mongo Aggregate JS 'every' equivalent

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using an `aggregate` and I'd like to add a `Boolean` `property` per `Document` for if all properties in a `subArray` on the `Document` are true.

In my example below...`CONFLICTS` is a subArray of Docs that each contain a `Boolean` `property` called `Resolved`. I just want to add a new `allResolved` field for if all Conflicts are resolved.

So..in my `addFields` stage, I have something like

```
 {
   '$project': {
      'allResolved': {
        '$allElementsTrue': '$CONFLICTS.resolved'
      }, 
    }
  }
```

so JS equivalent is `const allResolved = CONFLICTS.every(conflict => conflict.resolved)`

But this seems to always return `true` which is not correct

Comment: `$allElementsTrue` returned true if all elements of an array are true, and seems your query to be ok, check this [example](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70534916-m)

Comment: Yea, query seems fine, Red Herring on JS side is where I saw the false positive. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, edge case is that `conflicts` may not exist or its docs may not contain a `resolved` property. It'll always return true if this is the case. How may we account for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- this does extra checks
- check to be array
- to be not empty array
- and each member to be true (missing and nulls will be false)

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70534916-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"allResolved":
   {"$and":
    [{"$isArray":["$conflicts"]},
     {"$not":[{"$eq":["$conflicts", []]}]},
     {"$reduce":
      {"input":"$conflicts",
       "initialValue":true,
       "in":
       {"$and":[{"$eq":["$$this.Resolved", true]}, "$$value"]}}}]}}}])
```